# Throw custom Exceptions in Java/Android

Tags: java, android, exception

I'm developing a custom Exception class, in which I have the following constructors:

```
public class UserException extends Exception
{
    string message;
    public UserException() {
        super();
    }

    public UserException(String message, Throwable cause)
    {
        super(message, cause);

        this.cause = cause;
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

And I create a new custom exception like this:

```
private Camera.PreviewCallback SetPreviewCallBack() throws UserException {
    .......
    // Something went wrong
    throw new UserException("Something failed.", new Throwable(String.valueOf(UserExceptionType.CaptureFailed)));
 }
```

But when I insert my `throw new UserException(...)` it tells me to surround it with `try/catch`!! That's not the idea, isn't it? I want to throw custom exceptions when I need them to be thrown, without surronding my `new Exceptions` with more `try/catch` clauses.

So, what I'm doing wrong? What I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: where have you reached with this ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In addition to Eran's answer, you could also make your custom Exception extend `RuntimeException`, which does not need to be caught.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!! Extending RuntimeException works for my custome error where extending Exception wouldn't compile. I couldn't figure out how to suppress the "unhandled exception" message. Switching the exception type did the trick!

Comment: By the way: You don't need to re-introduce "message", it is already part of the base Exception.

Answer (score 10):

If the method that throws this exception doesn't handle it (i.e. it doesn't catch it), it must declare it in the `throws` clause, since this is a checked exception.

```
public void yourMethod () throws UserException
{
    ...
    throw new UserException("Something failed.", new Throwable(String.valueOf(UserExceptionType.CaptureFailed)));
    ...
}
```

Comment: I do so, and it still asks me to surround with try catch.

Comment: @Sonhja see my answer for 2nd part.

Answer (score 6):

if your Custom Exception extends from [Exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) class, it must be handled (using `try-catch`) or passed on to caller (using `throws`). If you just want to leave it to runtime to handle the exception, You need to extend it from [RuntimeException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html) Class
Since its the 1st case in your scenario, You should do something like this:

```
public void surroundingMethod() throws UserException{
    throw new UserException("Something failed.", new Throwable(String.valueOf(UserExceptionType.CaptureFailed)));
}
```

this will essentially pass your exception to the caller, so now it will be caller's responsibility to handle it with try-catch or pass it on again.

so again, u need to modify calling instruction as

```
public void callingMethod () {
    try {
        surroundingMethod();
    } catch (UserException ex){
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should either declare your methods as `throws UserException` - or make your exception extend [`RuntimeException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html).

The later is officially unadvised, but is often used to bypass the [java's declared exception mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/declaring.html).

Answer (score 2):

In Java, when you `throw` a *checked* `Exception`, there is one more thing you are required to do:

**1.** Either add a `try-catch` block around the `throw` and handle this `Exception` within the same method.

**2.** Or add a `throws` statement to the method definition, transferring the responsibility for the handling of the the `Exception` to a higher-level method.

This is part of the overall OOP paradigms of modularity & abstraction: who is responsible for handling an `Exception`, the caller of a method or the method itself ? The answer depends on the nature of the `Exception`.