# Retrofit 2 error response handling

Tags: android, retrofit

I have a method that downloads api data. But I get response with empty data, so I need to check if data is correct.

Call the method:

```
try {
        fetchChartData();
    } catch (EmptyResponseException e) {
        view.showError();
    }
```

And fetch data:

```
public void fetchChartData() throws EmptyResponseException {   
Call<ChartModel> dailyChartCall = ... //some call
dailyChartCall.enqueue(new Callback<ChartModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ChartModel> call, Response<ChartModel> response) {
            //EMPTY
            if(response.body().getData().size() == 0){
            <<-- THROW HERE
            } else ...
```

How should I implement exception and pass it to the top?
Simple 'throw new EmptyResponseException' is not working as onResponse  is anonymous class.

Comment: Instead of throwing exception why are you not using Toast,SnackBar or other alert message ?

Comment: I'm catching exception and showing text in activity

Comment: Also this function is used in 2 activities, so error needs to be handled in different ways

Comment: Please follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28693363/throw-custom-exceptions-in-java-android

Comment: Is `fetchChartData()` is in same activity where you have `try-catch` block?

Comment: @prashant17 yes

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are designing your app using MVP structure.

So instead of catching exception, you can do

```
   public void fetchChartData(){   
        Call<ChartModel> dailyChartCall = ... //some call
        dailyChartCall.enqueue(new Callback<ChartModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ChartModel> call, Response<ChartModel> response) {
            //EMPTY
            if(response.body().getData().size() == 0){
               ***presenter.showError();***
            } else ...
            {
              >>>> do your logic here <<<< 
              presenter.showChartData();
            }
```

Which in presenter showError and showChartData you can call corresponding view function.