# Throw an exception and print its stacktrace in the logcat at "error" level

Tags: android, exception, kotlin, logcat

I have a throwable object and I want to print its stacktrace in the logcat with an "`Log.e`" logging level (error). My method is throwing an exception, but the stacktrace is printed as a warning.

Here is My Code :

```
@Throws(RuntimeException::class)
fun throwErrorIfNotHttp (e: Throwable) {
    if (e is HttpException) {
        val code = e.code()
    } else if (e is SocketTimeoutException) {
        Log.e("time out", "time out")
    } else if (e is IOException) {
        Log.e("File error", "file error")
    } else {
       throw RuntimeException(e) // This  should appear as error
    }
}
```

Here is the image of exception .

[image]

**Edit**

My Extension Function:

```
fun <T> Observable<Response<T>>.makeRequest(
    context: Context,
    executeOnError: ((Any?) -> Unit)? = null, executeOnSuccess: (T?) -> Unit
): Disposable? {

   val disposable: Disposable = this
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe({
            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                executeOnSuccess(it?.body())
            } else {
                val error = getExceptionFromResponse(it, context)
                 handleError(error, context)

            }
        }, {
           throwErrorIfNotHttp(it)            
        })

    return disposable

}
```

How can I make it to show it in error tab instead of warning tab ?

Comment: Use try catch code

Comment: I don't want to catch exception , I want app to get crash and crash report to be shown in error tab instead of as warning .

Comment: Do you mean something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/28693384/9292949

Comment: Looks like you have an rxjava observable of sorts that is throwing. You need to do it where you're subscribing; now you have a `printStackTrace()` error handler there.

Comment: @laalto Yes I am getting `Throwable` from Rxjava and I want  handle all requests and error in a common place . So I am having an extension function which handles requests at common place . See Edit . So is there any way to do it here ?

Comment: What if you print the stacktrace in the logcat with e.printstacktrace()?

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi still shows as warning

Comment: @ManoharReddy what happens if you add Log.e("mytag", "mymessage",e); in your else statement?

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi That seems to work , Please add you answer , I will accept it tomorrow If there is no better way .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding to your else statement

```
Log.e(TAG, "mymessage",e);
```

Whole code:

```
@Throws(RuntimeException::class)
fun throwErrorIfNotHttp (e: Throwable) {
    if (e is HttpException) {
            val code = e.code()
    } else if (e is SocketTimeoutException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "time out")
    } else if (e is IOException) {
            Log.e(TAG, "file error")
    } else {
      Log.e(TAG, "mymessage",e);
      throw RuntimeException(e) // This  should appear as error
    }
 }

companion object{
  val TAG = "class_tag"
}
```